# What does :?> mean in f#?

Tags: f#, piping

Given the line:

```
let win = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) :?> Window
```

What is `:?>` doing?

I tried looking up ternary but not noticing the `:?`, it seems to be for type testing?. Also I know `>` is piping but Window does not  have any constructor parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the dynamic cast operator which has nothing to do with piping. I quote [MSDN section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx) on downcasting:

> The `:?>` operator performs a **dynamic cast**, which means that the success
>   of the cast is determined at run time. A cast that uses the `:?>`
>   operator is not checked at compile time; but at run time, an attempt
>   is made to cast to the specified type. If the object is compatible
>   with the target type, the cast succeeds. If the object is not
>   compatible with the target type, the runtime raises an
>   *InvalidCastException*.